# Vaadin combo-box: Load items on input

Tags: javascript, arrays, combobox, polymer, vaadin

I intend to use Vaadin combo-box https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-combo-box/

I intend to use it for data whose content will be loaded upon user input. Therefore `items` will be empty after pageload.

Q1: How do I set `items` only after 250ms of no-input into the field? I guess I have to listen to the https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-combo-box/#vaadin-combo-box:event-value-changed and fire from there if the last keypress was > 250ms.

Q2: Is there a way to style the list items with custom background eg. depending on an attribute in the object set for `items`?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful for you: https://blog.oio.de/2015/01/17/write-simple-auto-complete-combobox-vaadin/

Comment: Have you noticed the new `v1.2.0` version https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box/releases/tag/v1.2.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to assign the `items` based on user input. Since the `value-changed` event on combo-box is only fired after selection, it wont work for you. Instead you need to listen for `value-changed` on the input: `combobox.$.input`. On the event listener, use `debounce` to add the 250ms delay you are looking for.

For the styling question: currently it cant be done unfortunately. But the good news is that support for customization is on the roadmap:  https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box/issues/165